# Problem in setting or changing change CRS in R

Tags: r, gis, gdal

I was using the sf package for setting or changing the CRS (R version 4.2). For some other project, I had to update to the new version of the R (v4.3).

However, now I need to change the CRS of an object and I receive the following error:

```
In CPL_crs_from_input(x) :
  GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

I made a clean install and re-installed my previous packages (sf, raster, sp, and dependencies)
I tried to set proj.db environment

```
Sys.setenv(PROJ_LIB = "...\\AppData\\Local\\R\\win-library\\4.3\\sf\\proj")
```

I also tried going back to v4.2 But still, I am getting the same error. I am using the most basic commands and it is not working.

```
df <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4326")
df <- st_crs(4326)
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

Update: I tried it on another PC and it is working. So, the R version or packages are not an issue here. I need an idea to solve this or remove directories causing this problem without formatting the PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should never cross-post (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2302). Probably a duplicate of https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2298 on the failing PC. If so, use `Sys.setenv("PROJ_LIB"="")` before loading `sf`, as in https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2298#issuecomment-1864805440. To update `sf` to a patched version see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2298#issuecomment-1867563910.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
library(sf)
# Define a new CRS (for example)
newcrs <- st_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

# Change x object CRS 
x<- st_transform(x, crs = newcrs )
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. I get the error "Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) : cannot transform sfc object with missing crs"